# Grid N*N Pattern based on user's choice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to generate the board which will be always displayed as a grid with equal number of cells on each side based on user's choice (such as 3x3, 4x4).

Let's say user has chosen the option "3x3" on the website with `option value="9"`.
So I need to display:

```
box box box

box box box

box box box
```

Which N*N pattern will stay the same no matter how website resizes.

HTML:

```html
<div class="data">
  <label for="size-select">Choose a board size: </label>
  <select id="size-select">
    <option value="empty" selected>--Choose board size--</option>
    <option value="9">3x3</option>
    <option value="25">5x5</option>
    <option value="49">7x7</option>
    <option value="81">9x9</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

For example:

```js
function defineSquareSize(boardSize) {
  let board = id("board");
  board.innerHTML = "";
  if (boardSize !== "empty") {
    let boardNum = parseInt(boardSize);
    for (let i = 0; i < boardNum; i++) {
      let div = gen("div");
      let scenario = gen("p");

      scenario.classList.add("scenario");
      div.classList.add("square");

      board.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(scenario);
    }
  }
}
```

So now I have:

```
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

But I need to style each square with width and margin based on different user input in order to get N*N pattern.

With:

```css
.square {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
}
```

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: If you need a grid you should use a css grid instead of a css flexbox.

Comment: for 3x3 , you need 9 children of 33.33% of width and flex-wrap. , for grid : grid-template-colums:repeat(3,1fr) and the same for the rows. read the spec , but you did not show any of your code.

Comment: add more details, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

You can set `grid-template-columns`property in JavaScript retrieving the `option` value and therefore creating any type of board (as long it is a square board)

```js
const boardSizeSelect = document.querySelector('#size-select'),
  boardContainer = document.querySelector('.board-container')

boardSizeSelect.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const option = e.currentTarget,
    boardSize = Math.pow(option.value, 2)

  boardContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${option.value}, 1fr)`

  boardContainer.innerHTML = ''
  for (let i = 1; i <= boardSize; i++)
    boardContainer.innerHTML += `<div>${i}</div>`
})
```

```css
.board-container {
  display: grid;
}

/*demo only */

body {
  margin: 0
}

.board-container div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <label for="size-select">Choose a board size: </label>
  <select id="size-select">
    <option value="empty" selected>--Choose board size--</option>
    <option value="1">1x1</option>
    <option value="2">2x2</option>
    <option value="3">3x3</option>
    <option value="4">4x4</option>
    <option value="5">5x5</option>
    <option value="6">6x6</option>
    <option value="7">7x7</option>
    <option value="8">8x8</option>
    <option value="9">9x9</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class='board-container'></div>
```